# FreeBSD natd port forwarding

Tags: freebsd, port-forwarding

I'm trying to set up simple **natd** port forwarding on my FreeBSD router, so that I can get to local Win machine (192.168.20.10) via RDP from external network.

The configuration is following:
FreeBSD 12.0 machine with 2 NICs *igb0* and *igb1*. PPPoE internet connection on *igb0*. ISP gives me fixed public IP via DHCP, bringing up *tun0* interface, looking like this:

```
tun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1492
   options=80000<LINKSTATE>
   inet 91.122.x.x --> 91.122.y.y netmask 0xffffffff
   groups: tun
   nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
   Opened by PID 1149
```

(where `91.122.x.x` is my fixed public IP address)

LAN on *igb1*, internet access works on local machines.

Kernel is rebuilt with the following options:

```
#IPFW
 options         IPFIREWALL
 options         IPFIREWALL_VERBOSE
 options         IPFIREWALL_VERBOSE_LIMIT=30
 options         LIBALIAS
 options         IPFIREWALL_DEFAULT_TO_ACCEPT   # optional, won't let you lock out
 options         IPDIVERT

#PPPoE
 options         NETGRAPH
 option          NETGRAPH_PPPOE
 options         NETGRAPH_SOCKET
```

Configuration is the following:

```
root@beastiebox:/etc # cat rc.conf
hostname="beastiebox"
gateway_enable="YES"
ifconfig_igb0="DHCP"
ifconfig_igb1="inet 192.168.20.1 netmask 255.255.255.0"
mpd_flags="-b"
mpd_enable="YES"
sshd_enable="YES"
#NAT
natd_enable="YES"
natd_interface="igb0"
natd_flags="-f /etc/natd.conf"
#DHCP
dhcpd_enable="YES"
dhcpd_flag="-q"
dhcpd_conf="/usr/local/etc/dhcpd.conf"
dhcpd_ifaces="igb1"
dhcpd_withumask="022"
dhcpd_chuser_enable="YES"
dhcpd_withuser="dhcpd"
dhcpd_withgroup="dhcpd"
dhcpd_chroot_enable="YES"
dhcpd_devfs_enable="YES"
dhcpd_rootdir="/var/db/dhcpd"
#Firewall
firewall_enable="YES"
firewall_type="simple"
firewall_script="/etc/ipfw.rules"
firewall_logging="YES"
firewall_script="YES"
```

```
root@beastiebox:/etc # cat natd.conf
same_ports yes
use_sockets yes
#unregistered_only yes
redirect_port tcp 192.168.20.10:3389 3389
redirect_port udp 192.168.20.10:3389 3389
```

Firewall is transparent so far:

```
root@beastiebox:/etc # ipfw list
65535 allow ip from any to any
root@beastiebox:/etc #
```

I've already tried a lot of options, but still can not RDP to the local Win machine from outside. (It works if I swap my FreeBSD router with another one I used before).
I just don't understand what is blocking natd `redirect_port` rules when ipfw is configured to `allow ip from any to any`.

Please help me point out errors in my config.

Please do not suggest different ways (pf, etc) of port forwarding configuration, I'm specifically asking about **natd/ipfw**.

Comment: You are missing any `divert` rule in your IPFW configuration. See [the handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html) for details.

Comment: Do I need `divert` rule even if the firewall is transparent? And even if I set `firewall_type="OPEN"` or `firewall_enable="NO"` or just comment out all #Firewall section of my rc.conf? (I tried these options already). And if I set up `divert` ipfw rule why do I actually need natd `redirect_port` rules?

Comment: I mean, if I have to set up ipfw rules for port forwarding, can I do port forwarding with ipfw rules only, w/o natd at all? And can I set up port forwarding with natd only, w/o ipfw? I just do not understand what is blocking natd `redirect_port` rules if ipfw if configured to allow `from any to any`.

Comment: [The handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html) states that `natd` works in conjunction with `ipfw`. Take a look at `/etc/rc.firewall` for the example rules, but `OPEN` should create the `divert` rules. Check using `ipfw list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue finally.

I tried to kill **natd** just to restart it with some test options and I was totally stunned by the fact that LAN machines did not lose their internet connection after that.
I started investigating and discovered that I had another separate NAT working! That was `ppp nat` setup in `/etc/ppp/ppp.conf`. So, that was the root cause.
However I had to change some of my **natd/ipfw** settings in order for everything to work as intended.

First off, I changed `natd_interface="igb0"` to `natd_interface="tun0"` (from my external NIC to the interface pppoe bringing up on connect).
And I added the ipfw `divert` rule, looking like that:

`ipfw add divert natd from any to any via tun0`

Everything works fine after that and I'm proceeding with my firewall tuning now.